# C Reading input into an char array in loop

Tags: c, stdin

I am reading input from `stdin` e.g. name of car, type of car.

The problem I am facing is, if I entered number of cars 2 and I take
input in loop, the second value is overwritten to the first value via `scanf`.

Enter number of cars:2

Enter name of column :chevy

Type of car available can be electric,gas - Enter type of car :gas

Enter name of column :chevy2

Type of car available can be electric,gas - Enter type of car :electric

now if I print all I see is electric

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        setbuf(stdout, NULL);
        int carNum;
        int i;

        char carName[50];
        char carType[200];

        printf("\nEnter number of cars:");
        scanf("%d",&carNum);
        for(i=0;i<carNum;i++)
         {
             printf("\nEnter name of car :");
     scanf("%s", &carName[i]);

     printf("\nType of car available can be electric,gas - Enter type of car %d: ");                             
     scanf("%s", &carType[i]);
         }

         for(i=0;i<carNum;i++)
         {

             printf("\nName of car %d: ",i+1);
             printf("\n%s", &carName[i]);


             printf("\nType of car %d: ",i+1);
             printf("\n%c", &carType[i]);
         }  


        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**  New answer:

As you have shown you requirement that you wants to read some number of car names and types You need array of strings for `carName` and `cartype` instead of simple char array. like(for an essay solution):

```
 #define LEN 100     // declare sufficient length size 

 char carName[50][LEN];   // in main()
 char carType[50][LEN];
```

and your correct scanf and printf statements should be like this:

```
scanf("%d",&carNum);
for(i=0;i<carNum;i++){
    printf("\nEnter name of car :");
    scanf("%s", carName[i]);
    printf("\nType of car available can be electric,gas - Enter type ofcar: ");
    scanf("%s", carType[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<carNum;i++){
    printf("\nName of car %d: ",i+1);
    printf("\n%s", carName[i]);
    printf("\nType of car %d: ",i+1);
    printf("\n%s", carType[i]);
}
```

(*notice: when I user `%s` I give `char*` as argument in scanf as well as in printf*)
**old answer:** 
In first for loop, Your scanf statements are wrong :

```
     scanf("%s", &carName[i]);
                          ^  remove [i]
     scanf("%s", &carType[i]);
                          ^  remove [i]
```

You just need to write like:

```
    // printf
    scanf("%s", &carName);
    //print                    
    scanf("%s", &carType);
```

in Second loop in printf statements are wrong.

```
printf("\n%c", &carType[i]);
               ^  not need
```

correct is

```
printf("\n%c", carType[i]);
```

Also I think your requirement is:

```
printf("\n%s", carType);
```

Comment: you are right. I i need based on number of cars. I get car name and type etc.

Comment: @Mellowcandle actully two-three mistakes here

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan I am able to read input. I guess for print out i will need nestloop but how would i print the value like carName[j][i]?

Comment: @jamesT you also not need `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` I think

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan I am using CDT on win7 with gcc4 and gdb from cygwin and setbuf(stdout, NULL); prints the value in console otherwise it doesn't work for me. Your answers works like charms, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @jamesT That is good But read again my answer. and to be sure you understands things. ask if something is unclear to you.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan How can i pass carName and carType as 1D array to a function, having hard time with that. Can you please answer.Thanks

Comment: @jamesT just defined your function like  `void fun(char* carName, char* carTypr){ // function detonation }` and call this function like: `fun(carName, carType);` in main

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan, Thanks a lot. So in that function fun how would i assign the values of these two to another variable or say another 1D array. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The arrays you're declaring doesn't represent strings, it represents a continuous memory composed of 50 bytes, and 200 bytes. This is enough to store a single 50 character string, and 200 character string respectivly.
What you need is an array of strings, declared like this.

```
char * carnames[MAX_INPUT];
```

I sugesst you create a buffer for reading each string, and then use `strdup()` which will copy and allocate the string to it's place in carnames.

Here's an example:

```
char buffer[80];
char * carnames[MAX_INPUT];

for(i=0;i<carNum;i++)
{
  scanf("%s", buffer);
  carnames[i] = strdup(buffer);
}
```

Be aware that strdup allocates memory for the string, so once you're done you should free the memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's another possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your help and answer. I can't get that to work. C in Char should lowercase. I will try it another time.

Comment: I fixed it, this is auto capitalization of the Ipad